# Duda sobre parametros && en funciones

Tags: c++

Alguien me podría explicar que significa, un parámetro definido con &&.

Ejemplo:

```
strc::strc(strc && o) {
    data = std::move(o.data);
    o.data = nullptr;
    msg("move ctor");
}
```

Gracias.
JC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424064/what-does-mean-with-a-parameter-type-in-c

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&&` es un *modificador*, presente a partir de C++11, conocido como *rvalue reference* (referencia de lado derecho).

Es *similar* a la clásica *referencia* (&) de C++, con ciertas diferencias:

- El dato original al que hace referencia, **es mutable** (no existe `const &&`, es ilegal).
- El dato original al que hace referencia, **es temporal**.

Esto último requiere una explicación mas detallada. Veamos una simple función de ejemplo:

```
std::string dup( const std::string &arg ) { return std::string( arg ); }
```

Una función simple, que nos devuelve una copia del argumento; para usarla, podríamos hacer

```
std::string duplicated = dup( std::string( ) );
```

Veamos lo que sucede en esa línea:

1. Se crea una instancia de `std::string`, llamando a su constructor por defecto.
2. Se llama a `dup( )`, pasándole como argumento una referencia constante a la instancia recién creada.
3. Se ejecuta `dup( )` y se retorna.
4. **Se destruye** la instancia creada en el punto 1.

**Eso** es una instancia temporal; básicamente, un dato **que no está ligado a un identificador**.

Un detalle de esto, fuente de muchos errores, es lo siguiente:

```
std::string dup( string &&orig ) {
  std::string ret( orig );
  return ret;
}
```

Fíjate que `orig` es temporal **fuera de la función**, pero dentro de ella, **no lo es**. Dentro de la función **si tiene nombre**.

Esto es intencional, y permite ciertas facilidades de uso del lenguaje: permite **seguir utilizando código antiguo**.

Desde C++11, el compilador tiene en cuenta este modificador para elegir la función concreta a llamar:

```
std::string dup( const std::string &s ); // no temporal.
std::string dup( std::string &&s ); // temporal.
```

¿ Entonces, tenemos que definir 2 versiones de cada función ? Pues **no**, porque el compilador, **en ausencia de la versión `// temporal`, usa la versión `// no temporal`**. Y la única manera de conseguir esto es que, dentro de la función, un argumento `&&` se comporte igual que uno `&`.

Puede parecer algo confuso al principio, pero su uso proporciona una **importantísima optimización**: a partir de C++11, los objetos pueden copiarse (como antes) ... **y moverse**; detectamos si es temporal, y, en lugar de copiar, **movemos** los datos.

Esto repercute en menores operaciones de uso/liberación de recursos, entre ellos la memoria; ha sido historicamente el gran *talón de aquiles* de C++, y con este nuevo modificador, se ha avanzado muchísimo en ello. Personalmente, opino que solo esto es suficiente para dar el salto desde versiones anteriores.

Comment: Si dup fuera dup(&&) en lugar de dup(&), en la asignación std::string duplicated = dup( std::string( ) ), cambiaria en algo los 4 puntos que comentas?. Me ha quedado claro como trabaja, pero no acabo de ver la ventaja. Porque definido dup(&&) le mando también el objeto “mutable” ya que no se puede definir const “ilegal” pero después de la asignación. Se destruiría el objeto mutable?

Comment: Y otra cosa de ato q me queda en aire es, que al pasarlo así realmente el objeto se pasa recién construido por el constructor, y solo se puede usar dentro de la función a la que se asa. Pero no podremos pasar un objeto que haya sufrido cambios desde su creación no?

Comment: @Jcpardo Una ventaja: `std::string`; al existir `&&`, puedes **mover el puntero interno** de una a otra, ahorrándote una reserva/copia de memoria, y, **como no es const**, puedes poner en la temporal ese puntero interno como `nullptr`. Fíjate que copiarías **el puntero**, no **la memoria a la que apunta**. La mejora de rendimiento es **tremenda**.

Comment: @Jcpardo Si puedes pasar instancias que no son temporales; para eso se creó `std::move( INSTANCIA )`. Pero observa que las clases **tienen que estar preparadas** para obtener ventaja de esto; tienen que proporcionar métodos pensados para `&&`; si no los tienen, se llama a las versiones `&`, y no hay mejora.

Comment: @Jcpardo Es que `&&` es un tema **muy muy amplio**; en mi opinión, el *solito* basta y sobra para justificar la existencia de la versión C++11 (aunque tiene muchas mas cosas útiles).

Comment: El primer comentario de los tres podías explicármelo mejor no lo entiendo discúlpame. Si tengo un método & también paso la referencia, ahorro memoria y tiempo, no el objeto. Y si le quitara el const al parámetro también podía modificar el objeto. Luego que me aporta && de extra ? Q le puedo pasar la llamada al constructor como parámetro y antes deberían pasarle una instancia creada precisamente y asignada a una variable?